# Could a positron be made to stably orbit an atom?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, atomic-structure, exotic-atoms

Suppose you have a single atom of neon, argon or some other noble gas of your choice. While the entire atom is electrically neutral a nearby positron would probably be more strongly attracted to the electron cloud than it would be repelled by the nucleus [since the nucleus is arguably further away]

I wonder if this means, given sufficient energy (but not too much), if it is possible for the positron to form a positron orbital around the atom.

Has this been done? Could it be feasible?

Comment: It would probably mutually circling with a particular electron before their fast annihilation. See also [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium).

Comment: Besides positronium, I guess there might be some short-lived bound states of (positron + normal atom).

Comment: Neon is a very complex atom. Forget about it for the time being. What do you think will happen if you had an anti-proton and positron just like normal hydrogen has a proton and an electron? What will happen to its spectra? If you were another world, you would not be able distinguish the normal hydrogen spectrum and the anti-hydrogen atom!

Comment: I wonder if some insight could be gained from the analytical solution of the Schrödinger equation for the $\ce{H2^+}$ cation (or maybe even the $\ce{HD^+}$ cation), if the mass for one of the hydrogen nuclei can somehow be allowed to vary all the way down to the mass of a positron. There's even a chance that, should a bound $\ce{Hp+}$ system exist, it may have a *longer* half-life than positronium, because the hydrogen nucleus will try to spatially separate the electron and positron, due to their respective attraction and repulsion.

Comment: A positron cannot orbit an atom. As soon as it will approach an ordinary electron, both would be annihilated, and transformed into two gamma-rays.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Nice idea, in principle the Hamiltonian is the same so, after adapting the mass, you could take the bound states of that solution and answer "yes" to the question. The problem is H2+ is normally solved within the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, which will not be applicable here at least when considering the behaviour of the electron and positron.

Comment: Inspired somewhat by @NicolauSakerNeto one idea to get at least an answer is to solve separately for an isolated hydrogen atom and an isolated positron, and then use the coupling terms between them as a perturbation. All you have to do then is prove that there is at least one state of the system with E<0 to answer the problem. Much too tired to solve that now, but it might not even be too bad, the perturbation will be much weaker than in the comparable case where perturbation theory is used in the helium atom.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto, your idea seems to be worked out in [this](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.83.052512) per by Matyús etc al.

Comment: As far as [exotic atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_atom) go, positron is essentially a *nucleus* not a electron. Binding it to an atom makes a molecule, not a bigger atom. For example there's [positronium hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium_hydride).

Comment: Without going into the mathematics, as others have done, consider that an "orbit" describes the **probability** of finding a particle. So, if there is even a *very small, but non-zero* chance that the antiparticle gets within a certain distance to a normal electron (cloud)... Poof! you have two 0.5 Mev photons, and two fewer particles. This applies to any metastable quantum system... eventually, they decay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Positron chemistry](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789814540148) is a thing, though experimental lifetimes are in the nanosecond range due to annihilation.

The noble gases seem to have a relatively favourable electron configuration, reserving a separate shell for any positron that might care to join $-$ thus minimising the risk of premature encounters with their negative brethren. However, in order to bind an electron an atom must either have net electrical charge or an unfilled electron shell. The noble gases have neither.

Halide ions are more attractive, and have been [observed](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0301010479800130) to bind positrons to form $\ce{[X-;e+]}$. Nevertheless, the positron [appears](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168583X00000057) not to form an atomic orbital in these cases (possibly impeded by the large size of $\ce{X-}$ ions), but rather acts as a second nucleus in a molecule, as with [positronium hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium_hydride).

Positrons can of course form stable orbitals around antiatoms, as evidenced by the synthesis of [antihydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihydrogen#Production) at CERN, but stable orbitals appear out of reach for normal atoms.